# TensorFlow: When a graph is frozen, do the preprocessing operations also get frozen if they are defined within the graph?

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning

My graph that was frozen had the following structure:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
    tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO) #Set the verbosity to INFO level

    #First create the dataset and load one batch
    dataset = get_split('train', dataset_dir, file_pattern=file_pattern)
    images, _, labels = load_batch(dataset, batch_size=batch_size)
....
```

where the `load_batch` function is the part where I preprocess tensors in my graph before feeding them for inference during the training process. If I have frozen my graph for serving purposes, then would the preprocessing operations for my images in `load_batch` gets frozen as well?

when I did a check using:

```
#print the operations available
count = 0
for op in graph.get_operations():
    print op.name
    count+=1 
    if count == 300:
        break
```

I could not find the operations that are preprocessing my tensors, as the op names only show the conv layers weights, batchnorm and etc. - does this mean my graph's preprocessing parts are gone during the freezing process?

If the preprocessing components are gone, then is there a way to edit the graph so that I could insert the preprocessing operations after defining the Input tensor?

Comment: How did you freeze the graph? Typically, the freezing transformation will eliminate graph nodes that aren't on a path between the input tensor(s) and output tensor(s), so it may be possible to change the arguments to the script and retain the preprocessing nodes.

Comment: I followed the guide mainly from this tutorial:https://blog.metaflow.fr/tensorflow-how-to-freeze-a-model-and-serve-it-with-a-python-api-d4f3596b3adc and from what I read the main idea it did was to import a meta_graph into the default graph and convert it into a graph_def, which will be used in the `convert_variables_to_constant` function.